# Difference between 'return object' and 'return Ok(object)'

Tags: asp.net-web-api

(a)

```
var person = repository.GetPerson(id)
return person;
```

(b)

```
var person = repository.GetPerson(id)
return Ok(person);
```

According to the developer tools the result is the same and the status code is always 200. Is there a difference? If there is no difference, should I use the Ok() method or OkResult anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both are examples are code inside an endpoint for an HTTP GET call, they are effectively the same.

There might be a slight difference in implementation, but the net result will be the same: the payloads in either case are identical (e.g. JSON or some other representation), and the status code will be identical, `200`.

It's a good practice to be explicit though, and use `return Ok(person)` because this is both succinct and reveals the intent more obviously than `return person`. You could also do `return new OkObjectResult(person)`, which is intention revealing but not succinct. (ref: [OkObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

Finally, [OkResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0) should only be used when you don't want to return a payload. This is equivalent to `return Ok()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is caused by the two implicit conversions on `ActionResult<T>`.

One is from the regular `ActionResult`. `Ok("string)` is an `ActionResult` (more specifically an `OkObjectResult`). So a method that returns `ActionResult<User>` will allow `return Ok("string")`.

The second implicit conversion is from `T`. So `return new User()` will also be implicitly converted to `ActionResult<User>`.

This means that, while `Ok(object)` is very useful and arguably more explicit, the compiler is more likely to surface a type error if you avoid using `Ok()` and stick to returning the actual object.